# Basic Questions about SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5

Tags: sql-server

1) Is SSCE (SQL Server Compact Edition) a local only database? Meaning I can't access it from anywhere else but the host machine?

2) It supports up to 256 connections locally?

3) Are there any good tools available for converting an empty mdf with no stored procedures or triggers to a CE sdf?

4) When you run the install for this, does it open any ports at all? I wouldn't think so but my boss is convinced it does.

5) Does SQL Server Management Studio open any ports by default upon installation?

Thanks for reading and any insight you can provide :)

Comment: SQL DBO or other IT administrators on ServerFault might be able to come up with other answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes. It is a local only DB, and cannot be accessed from other machines
2. Not sure, I've never hit a
   limit, but I know that there is a
   4GB limit on the file size
3. None that I'm aware of
4. Again, none that I'm
   aware of (at least my software and
   corporate firewalls haven't been
   complaining)
5. Again, none that I'm
   aware of. The Management Studio
   itself is not the DBMS package
   (which does require some ports to be
   opened). That said, I've never tried
   to install the Management STudio
   without either SQL DEVELOPER or SQL
   EXPRESS.

Just a note: I answered Question #1 on the concept of attempting to use the SSCE as a SERVER which a secondary computer attaches to, as opposed to mounting the DB File from a Shared Drive. For example, in SQL Express, I can place an instance onto a server, and have multiple applications connect to it, and I can also mount the file associated with a DB into my local instance of SQL Express from a shared drive. In SSCE, one can mount the file, but can't act as a server.

Answer (score 3):

1. the database file (normally an sdf) can happily be on a remote share but only one remote machine can access it at a time.
2. It supports [256 connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983341(VS.80).aspx) which can be from different processes.
3. Don't know sorry - I have used [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlCompactCoptUtility.aspx) with some minor edits to copy from sql server effectively.
4. When *installing* from the package it might try to ping the windows update service for an up to date check (I haven't checked) when running via an xcopy deployment I see no open ports (you do not need to install SqlServerCE, simply placing the required dll in your private bin path (normally the same folder as the executable) is sufficient.
5. I don't know

As to the open ports the best way to check is simply to do an install with something like wireshark running.